Join block not invoked although the two calling blocks exited successfully
I have 2 transform blocks that are joined into a join block but I sometimes have an issue where both transform blocks finish successfully and the join block is not invoked.
Relevant code snippet and the dataflow options I have configured:
TransformBlock<Person, Car> transformBlockGetCarInformation
    = new TransformBlock<Person, Car>(GetCarInformation, executionOption);

TransformBlock<Person, Person> transformBlockCollectPersonInfomation
    = new TransformBlock<Person, Person>(CollectPesonInfomation, executionOption);

JoinBlock<Person, Car> joinBlockUnionAllInfomation
    = new JoinBlock<Person, Car>(joinOption);

transformBlockGetCarInformation.LinkTo(joinBlockUnionAllInfomation.Target1);
transformBlockCollectPersonInfomation.LinkTo(joinBlockUnionAllInfomation.Target2);

dataOptions = new DataflowLinkOptions 
{ PropagateCompletion = true,
 MaxMessages = -1,
 Append = true };

blockOption = new DataflowBlockOptions {
BoundedCapacity = 1000, 
EnsureOrdered = true, 
MaxMessagesPerTask = 10, }; 

executionOption = new ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions 
{ MaxMessagesPerTask = 10, 
SingleProducerConstrained = true, 
MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 1, 
BoundedCapacity = 100000, }; 

joinOption = new GroupingDataflowBlockOptions 
{ Greedy = true, 
BoundedCapacity = 10000, 
EnsureOrdered = true, 
MaxMessagesPerTask = 10, }; 

I have logs in the relevant functions and I can see clearly that I did not get any error, the exit log of the two transform blocks were printed while the entry log of the join block was never printed.

Can you reproduce this in a simple console app?

@Fildor yes it's a typo, fixed. thanks

@MatthewWatson no, it is very hard to reproduce even in the original program, in a simple console app It's probably impossible.

"it is very hard to reproduce even in the original program" - so, it's not "not working" always but intermittently?

The chances of anyone here diagnosing an intermittent multithreading issue like that without a repro is close to zero....
